# Add a value to each cell in a Pandas dataframe column if another column contains a certain string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a very long and complicated Pandas dataframe in Python consisting of many columns, but an example would be something like:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data = None, columns = ['file','comment','number'])
df_test.file = ['file_1', 'file_1_v2', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4', 'file_4_v2', 'file_5']
df_test.comment = ['old', 'Replacing: file_1', 'none', 'new: 3', 'maybe', 'Replacing: file_4', 'none']
df_test.number = ['12', '12', '13', '13', '14', '14', '15']
```

What this shows is that the dataframe contains the names of several files which each has a comment and a number associated with them. Here, the files which has a comment that starts with 'Replacing: ' should have the same value in 'number' as the file it is replacing, but other files should not have the same number, as you can see that 'file_2' and 'file_3' has.

What I want to do is to increase the 'number' value whenever a duplicate of that value is found for both the duplicate and all files after that, as long as the 'comment' cell does not start with the string 'Replacing: '. This means that the 'number' column should end up looking like:

```
[12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 16]
```

I figured it might work with a for- and if-loop, but I'm really not sure and any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
(~df_test['comment'].str.startswith('Replacing:')).cumsum().add(11)
```

output:

```
0    12
1    12
2    13
3    14
4    15
5    15
6    16
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was looking for something more general which adds a one to all the numbers that already exist for duplicates and those below except for those that have the comment 'Replacing: '. This method works fine for the example, but will not work in the actual dataframe. Any idea on how to generalize it more?

Comment: Your logic is not clear. So I just solved an example. i think that using my answer and your pandas knowledge, you should be able to reach the desired output. If you need help, please explain why every number is the number. The logic you simply say is not clear